# Same Django Models Shared in two different Projects hosted at different urls

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, django-models

I have hosted a django project with one app on [heroku] (keshavbits.herokuapp.com). I have few models with too many data inside it. Now I wanted an another **django project** that will be hosted at **example.herokuapp.com** with *same settings,views and everything* as it is in keshavbits.herokuapp.com. Now the question is how can I access the Database hosted at keshavbits.herokuapp.com in the example.herokuapp.com.

Or how can I share databases b/w these two apps at different locations?

Comment: Well you can host database on separate domain and have an API in frontend of it. Then you can call the API endpoints on both of your domains to do CRUD operations on the centralised database.

Comment: Is it possible to solve my query without using API and hosting dedicated Centralized server ?